# install Maven plugin before it is executed

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

I have one. Parent-module and two Child. One of the child is a plugin I wrote for sending mail to email(mail parameters, themes, text are set in pom.xml), which should be sent during the compilation phase of the parent-module. The second child is just a class with "Hello World".

My question. How do I do in the parent module: install maven plugin before the compilation phase?

p.s. I can not correctly form a question, because a huge request to clarify the nuances in the comments or add the missing information.

upd:

this is child-plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.live.hello</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <artifactId>child-plugin</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

this is child-app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.live.hello</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>child-app</artifactId>

</project>
```

and parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.live.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>child-plugin</module>
        <module>child-app</module>
    </modules>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>com.live.hello</groupId>
                <artifactId>test1-send</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-exe-plugin</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sendEmail</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <loginSeander>my.test@gmail.com</loginSeander>
                            <passwordSender>11111111</passwordSender>
                            <mailRecipient>mymail@gmail.com</mailRecipient>
                            <subject>My first messege</subject>
                            <text>Hello!</text>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you want to send an email using the plugin after the other child module is compiled? In which module's pom do you call the plugin? Updating the question with all 3 pom.xml files would help answering the question.

Comment: @Smile i added more information

Comment: @Smile

>>"Do you want to send an email using the plugin after the other child module is compiled? In which module's pom do you call the plugin?"

Yes

Comment: Why do you like to send a mail via a build tool? I suppose it would be better to use a CI solution which handles that...

Comment: @khmarbaise this is my study-task

Comment: So what error do you get when you call `mvn clean install` on the parent?

Comment: Please update your question with output/error when you run `mvn clean install`